# Suppress ClientAbortException in struts2 VelocityResult class

Tags: java, struts2

I am getting the following stack trace in my log file and was wanting to suppress just this error from displaying in the log:

> ERROR 08-09-26 14:48:45.141
>   http-80-215
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.VelocityResult:
>   Unable to render Velocity Template,
>   '/jsondata.vm' ClientAbortException: 
>   java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

I understand what causes the error, and it is not really exceptional in this particular use case; I just want to suppress the ClientAbortException from displaying in the log file, but display a debug level message instead.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you can set log level for the class `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.VelocityResult` to `fatal`.