# Aborted Ajax call gives ClientAbortException / Broken pipe in server log: How to catch / suppress?

Tags: exception, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy, error-logging

I'm running a Jboss server with, among other things, a JAX-RS Web service (using the resteasy-2.3.6.Final bundled with Jboss / EAP).

When a client aborts a call to the server, the Resteasy `SynchronousDispatcher` can (obviously) not send the response back to the client which causes a bunch of errors at the `[SEVERE]` and `[ERROR]` level to show up in my server logs.

However, I don't consider these as actual errors, so I don't want to see them. Particularly as this is bound to happen often once the service will be in public use.

Here is the log output I want to suppress:

```
12:50:38,938 SEVERE [org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) Failed executing GET /ajax/findPerson: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.WriterException: ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponse.writeTo(ServerResponse.java:262) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    ....

Caused by: ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:403) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:356) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:426) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:415) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    ...

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:711) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:450) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:351) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    ...

12:50:38,942 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/myapplication].[MyAjaxApplication]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-2) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet MyAjaxApplication threw exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:392) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:152) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    ...
```

Is there an elegant way to do that?

By [writing my own](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.6.Final/userguide/html/ExceptionHandling.html) `ExceptionMapper` I managed to prevent the first one (the `[SEVERE]`) and turn it into a debug-level one-line log output, but the second one is still there. Frankly, I have no idea where to even start looking.

I've seen in another SO question that [I could just set the log level for one or both classes that throw the errors to a higher level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141248/suppress-clientabortexception-in-struts2-velocityresult-class), say `[FATAL]`, but I'd consider this more of a workaround...

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In the JBoss standalone.xml configuration file, go to the logging subsystem (e.g by searching for 
    `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.5">` if you are using EAP 6.4.0), and then add a logger for the category for which you want to suppress the errors. For your example if you want to suppress the logs for org.jboss.resteasy then your logger would look like

```
<logger category="org.jboss.resteasy">
    <level name="OFF"/>
</logger>
```

Setting the level to OFF should suppress the logger from logging the errors in the package org.jboss.resteasy

Comment: But then I wouldn't get ANY resteasy logging. Even at the level of the offending class ("SynchronousDispatcher"), I'd rather want THIS ONE exception suppressed, not all log output from that class.